# How to unlink all the symlinks under the directory?

Tags: linux

I would like to unlink the symbolic links like this:

```
unlink *
```

However it says `unlink: extra operand`

I would like to only delete the link file, keep original file.

Comment: I think the problem is that `unlink` doesn't accept more than one file

Comment: Also, you may wish to use `rm`, it has the exact same effect as `unlink` for files.

Comment: Use find with `-exec` or `xargs`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the "*" you're trying to unlink all files and directories under your current location.

unlink can't handle files or directories, it can handle only links, use the find command to find all links and unlink them, like this:

```
find . -type l -exec unlink {} \;
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks! `find . -type l` is useful as well.

Comment: `unlink` can remove any kind of file on my system. `rm` calls the `unlink` system call anyway

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid spawning other processes with `find … -exec …`. When you need to `unlink` or `rm` the results of `find`, use its [`-delete`](https://superuser.com/q/1222165/432690) option instead.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -delete
```

This command will find all the symlinks (`-type l`) in current directory (not in subdirectories; your `*` doesn't descend to subdirectories so I assume this is what you want) and delete them. The default behavior is not to follow symlinks, so the original files won't be affected.

Answer (score 1):

This command will find and remove all symlinks in current folder, it will not recurse into subfolders, and it will ignore dotfiles

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l ! -name '.*' -delete
```