# Delete old files in a folder excluding subfolders with a batch

Tags: linux, batch

i was wondering how to auto-delete old files in a certain folder but i want it to exclude its subfolders. I know how to automate the process and i know how to delete old files including subfolders:

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

To automate i just let it open at startup once.

Comment: And how to add more folders to search for? Just copy paste the same line? I mean in the same script, ofc.

Comment: How about something like: `find /path/to/files/* -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man 1 find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

> `-maxdepth levels`
>   Descend at most `levels` (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the command line arguments. `-maxdepth 0` means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.

```
find /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2 /foo/bar/fileA -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} +
```

Notes:

- Sole `rm` works well with files, not directories, and you want only files to be deleted, hence `-type f`.
- `-exec rm {} \;` was replaced by `-exec rm {} +`. Consider `-delete` (see [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1222237/432690)).
- If your `find` doesn't support `-maxdepth` then see how to [limit POSIX `find` to specific depth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618).