# Delete files older than... does nothing

Tags: ssh

I have a directory I'm in.
I can see there's tons of files in it.
When I run:

```
find ./ -type f -mtime +1400
```

It prints out a lengthy list.  Not exaggerated long thou.
I'm attempting to delete these files so I run:

```
find ./ -type f -mtime +1400 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

When I run the above command nothing happens.  No error it just hangs there for a while. It's been over 10 minutes and it's still there.
Any ideas how I could delete those items?

Comment: Most likely it is in the process of deleting the files - depending on your file system and medium type this can be a lengthy process.

Comment: Abort the process (Ctrl+C) and invoke again, this time with `rm -v …` (if your `rm` supports this) or with `-print` at the very end. This way you will see pathnames of files being deleted.

Comment: both comments were great, thank you! It indeed was just taking a long time as it worked.  Print helped me to see them as they're being deleted.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1222237/432690) for some hints related to performance; in your case `… -delete -print`, if `-delete` is supported..