# find + how to delete files that exists only on specific folder

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, find, rm

to delete files on under folder we can use the following approach with find

```
find /home -type f -delete
```

but how to delete recursive only the files that exists under temp folder ?

lets say we have the following example of temp path

```
/home/bla/bla/temp
/home/test/temp
/home/subf/subf/subf/temp
.
.
.
/home/1/temp
```

how to change the find syntax in order to delete only the files under `temp` directory

*the target is to use find command in order to match only the temp folders and remove the files under temp directory*

Comment: So you want to delete all files inside any directory named `temp`, *but* not the directory itself? Please confirm. `-type f` in your example matches regular files, but you keep saying "files". [This is a broad term](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). Do you really mean (all) files? or regular files? Removing regular files only will leave directories, symlinks, sockets and such intact. Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: I answered the question according to my interpretation of it. If you clarify (see my first comment) and the answer needs to be adjusted to the new interpretation then I will adjust it.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/708434/108618).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command will find regular files in any directory named `temp` and below, below `/home`.

```
find /home -type f -path '*/temp/*'
```

To actually delete them:

```
find /home -type f -path '*/temp/*' -delete
```

Notes:

- By default `find` does not follow symlinks. See `man 1 find` for options `-L`, `-H` and (if supported) `-P`.
- `-delete` is not portable. If your `find` does not support `-delete`, use [`-exec rm {} +`](https://superuser.com/a/1222237/432690). `-delete` is better not only because it doesn't create an additional process. It is safer as it (at least `-delete` implemented in GNU `find`) removes the race condition where someone may be able to make you remove the wrong file(s) by changing some directory to a symlink in-between the time `find` finds a file and `rm` removes it. The fact our `find` command does not follow symlinks is irrelevant at this point.