# Can you tag a file with metadata and later search for files by metadata?

Tags: linux, macos, posix

I would like to tag generated files with `generated: true`. Then later I'd like to find and remove all generated files `rm -rf ....`

Right now I'm including `generated` in the filename `filename.generated.go` where I can remove them with `rm -rf **/*.generated.*` - but I'm wondering if there's a way to omit it from the filename

Answer (score 4):

In Linux see [`man 7 xattr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html):

> Extended attributes are name:value pairs associated permanently with files and directories, similar to the environment strings associated with a process.  An attribute may be defined or undefined. If it is defined, its value may be empty or non-empty.
>
> […]
>
> User extended attributes may be assigned to files and directories for storing arbitrary additional information such as the mime type, character set or encoding of a file. The access permissions for user attributes are defined by the file permission bits: read permission is required to retrieve the attribute value, and writer permission is required to change it.

You can set an extended attribute with [`setfattr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfattr.1.html):

> Add extended attribute to user namespace:
>
> ```
> $ setfattr -n user.foo -v bar file.txt
> ```

In your case the command will be like:

```
setfattr -n user.generated -v true filename.go
```

You can retrieve the value with [`getfattr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getfattr.1.html):

```
getfattr --only-values -n user.generated filename.go
```

The following command will test if the value is equal* to `true` (by comparing strings):

```
[ "$(getfattr --only-values -n user.generated filename.go 2>/dev/null)" = true ]
```

Exit status `0` indicates equality.

<sup>*Note because of the way `$()` works, all trailing newlines are removed before comparison.</sup>

Now we can use this command as a test in `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    [ "$(getfattr --only-values -n user.generated "$1" 2>/dev/null)" = true ]
' find-sh {} \; -print
```

Notes:

- Add [`-delete`](https://superuser.com/q/1222165/432690) if you want.
- `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)
- You tagged `linux`, `macos`, `posix`. My expertise is in Linux, I know nothing about macOS. Extended attributes are certainly beyond POSIX.
- For extended attributes to work, the filesystem must support them. [Not all filesystems do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata).
- Extended attributes may be lost when a file is moved to another filesystem or copied. GNU `cp` with right options is able to copy them (see `man 1 cp` where it mentions `xattr`).
- There are other tools that can be used instead of `setfattr`/`getfattr`. At least `attr` and `xattr`. Examples:

  ```
  attr -qg generated filename.go
  xattr -p user.generated filename.go
  ```

  See `man 1 attr` and `man 1 xattr` for details.