# Tag folders/files in Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, backup

I'm trying to create a simple bash script to copy a lot of files to another disk, like a backup. I know I can create a database to keep track of which files I already copied but I would like to know if there is a way to tag those files/folders, then I can just check: the tag=copied exist. If yes, just ignore it and go to the next file.

I'm just trying to find a better way to copy file/folders using the Operation System features instead of creating something myself.

Comment: For Linux: [*Can you tag a file with metadata and later search for files by metadata?*](https://superuser.com/q/1734380/432690)

Comment: What about using `rsync`?

Comment: Ty, this will give me some insights on where to start.