# On Linux, how can one diff directories, excluding files by name, but including directories of the same name?

Tags: linux, shell, diff

Consider the following dir/file structure (all leaf nodes are regular files, not that it really matters):

```bash
$ tree
.
├── cool_1
│   ├── dumb
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   └── file2
│   └── foo
│       └── dumb
└── cool_2
    ├── dumb
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    └── foo
        └── dumb
```

I want to do a recursive diff of the two directories, excluding the **regular files** `<root>/foo/dumb` but not the entire **directories** `<root>/dumb`.

I've looked at `--exclude` and `--exclude-from` in `man 1 diff` and if there's a way to make a pattern that would do this, I'm at a loss, other than writing a script that does the recursion by hand or something like that. How can I compare directories and exclude what I want and only what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want `diff -r cool_1 cool_2` with exclusions.

`--exclude` and `--exclude-from` are indeed [too limited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507520/108618).

There is a method, somewhat cumbersome but quite straightforward in its core:

1. Copy the two directories you want to `diff` to elsewhere. E.g. let the target directory be `target/`. Our basic command  is then `cp -R cool_1 cool_2 target/`.

   Notes:

   - You want `target/` not to contain `cool_1` or `cool_2` beforehand. A good idea is to create a new empty directory (`mkdir target`) and then `cp` to it.
   - You want `-P` (copy symbolic links as symbolic links).
   - Ideally the whole directory hierarchies in `cool_1` and in `cool_2` belong to a single filesystem. If so, choose the target directory inside the same filesystem and then:

     - use `cp -l` and create hardlinks to regular files instead of actually copying them (your `cp` may or may not support `-l` though);
     - alternatively create reflinks with `cp --reflink=always`, if the filesystem supports reflinks and if your `cp` supports `--reflink`. Without a good reason for reflinks, you should go with hardlinks. A good reason for reflinks is when some regular file below `cool_1` or `cool_2` is immutable and you cannot create a new hardlink to it.

     This way you will avoid unnecessary actual copying. It's not only about I/O, hardlinking or reflinking will consume far less additional diskspace than actual copying.

   The command will be like:

   ```
    cp -RPl cool_1 cool_2 target/
   ```
2. Go to the target directory:

   ```
   cd target/
   ```

   Make sure there was no error and you are in the target directory.
3. Use whatever means to actually *remove* files you want to exclude. Remove them by hand with `rm`, or in `mc`, or with some automation. E.g. this command:

   ```
   find cool_1 cool_2 -name dumb ! -type d -delete
   ```

   will remove all files inside `cool_1` or `cool_2` with basename `dumb` except files of the type directory. `-delete` is not portable, use `-exec rm {} \;` instead if necessary; see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1222165/432690). If the target directory (which is now our `.`) contains only `cool_1` and `cool_2` then you can simplify and act on the entire directory: `find . …`

   You may find this question useful: [*Recursively search files with exclusions and inclusions*](https://superuser.com/q/1577775/432690).

   Use `tree` to inspect if the hierarchy looks good. You can also run like `diff -r cool_1 ../cool_1` and `diff -r cool_2 ../cool_2` to see what you have removed. In case you remove too much, remember you can always copy (hardlink, reflink) again from the original directory.

   Because you can remove (or re-add) files even one by one, it's possible to attain arbitrary exclusions.
4. Use `diff -r` inside the target directory:

   ```
   diff -r cool_1 cool_2
   ```

   Here `cool_1/` and `cool_2/` do not contain files you wanted to exclude, so there is no need to tell `diff` to exclude anything.
5. Eventually remove the target directory:

   ```
   cd .. && rm -r target/
   ```